# ASP.NET Displaying a loading icon for long page response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel

I am generating an Excel document on button click, however the document takes up to 25 seconds to generate and I would like a loading icon to display until the response has finished.

I am using spin.js and showing the icon on button click but I'm having trouble figuring out how to hide it once the page response has completed.

What would be the best way to handle this? I don't think ajax works in this situation.

Not sure if it's needed but the response code once the Excel file has been generated is as follows.

```
...

With HttpContext.Current.Response
  .Clear()
  .ClearHeaders()
  .ClearContent()
  .ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  .AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Product_Documents_Report_" & Now.ToShortDateString & ".xlsx")
  .AddHeader("Pragma", "Public")
  .ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default
End With

Dim msOutput As New MemoryStream

eppExport.SaveAs(msOutput)
eppExport.Dispose()
eppExport = Nothing

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", msOutput.Length.ToString())

msOutput.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)
msOutput.Close()
msOutput.Dispose()

HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

Comment: I did something similar using John Culver's Jquery pluging. Requires some research but works like a charm. http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/. The trick is to generate a cookie server side once the document is generated. And make a listener on the client to wait for that cookie. Some examples here : http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Comment: why you don't use a simple div show and hide?